Cannot find "SharedTransitionScope" in the release mode (android)
I am using "Shared Element Transitions in Compose" and it works fine in debug mode. But when I change it to the release mode, there is an error that it couldn't find the "SharedTransitionScope". Has anyone experienced a similar error? I want to know how to solve it.
Error :
Unresolved reference 'ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi'.
Unresolved reference 'SharedTransitionScope'.
Unresolved reference 'ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi'.
Annotation argument must be a compile-time constant.
Unresolved reference 'SharedTransitionScope'.

The part of the code that causes the error
import androidx.compose.animation.ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi
import androidx.compose.animation.SharedTransitionScope
...
@OptIn(ExperimentalSharedTransitionApi::class)
@Composable
fun SharedTransitionScope.HomeScreen(


Include the dependency implementation snippet from the gradle file for further clarification.

Check your libraries for shared element transition, when I see that error in my project, I saw there are multiple different library version for shared element transition. If it is so for your app, make your library restricted to specific version

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Anyone who is having this kind of trouble, it will be fixed by updating the version related to SharedTransitionScope. It seems like it’s fixed now.
